# Salesforce fields recover options

Tags: fields, custom, delete, activity

New here, thanks for your help.
I have salesforce cloud enterprise. We had a third party trying to setup their software for scheduling and it was done in the live environment not our sandbox.
Issue is they had to delete some custom activity fields. (I can’t find the original fields in the deleted fields section)(not in the recycle bin that we can see)
I do have the fields in a sandbox but they don’t hold any of the data.
I was after some advice.
Can I recover the fields from else where?
If I deploy them back in from the sandbox, is there an easy way to get the formulas etc. back?
I’m gushing the background data will have been deleted when the field was deleted is that correct?
Final thing I have just been told that our salesforce isn’t backed up as the product we use has gone end of life. So having a good time all round.

All help appreciated

Cheers

Comment: was your org using the weekly Data Export feature?

Comment: Open a support case with Salesforce. They're generally sympathetic to data loss scenarios and might help you.

Comment: Hi thanks guys. No the org wasn’t using the weekly data export feature but are now. I will attempt to log a case with salesforce thanks. I suppose I was secretly hoping they had some magic backup they don’t tell people about.